# Can demigod city be spared from divine judgement by staying neutral?

Tags: magic, warfare, super-powers, gods, geopolitics

Lately more and more worshippers are becoming materialistic and are abandoning their faith emass, this has been brought up to the attention of the Olympian god who suspect it was the doing of the demigods whom had undo many disasters obviously an act of defiance.

Lately the demigod had returned one of the 4 only divine beasts which had the power to devour the entire Mount Olympus a hundred times over supposedly an act to appease the god and in exchange to be left alone, a decision which the demigod soon regret as they now have to brave the divine punishment.

To the people the demigod city served as a bridge to connect them to the god but the demigod knows better, it is the only wall that separates the 2 realms. Fearing one day the god might sent a divine beast called Armageddon to wreck havoc on Earth, no one dares to do anything that may seem like a blasphemy.

My question is despite being sandwiched between 2 different planes like heaven and earth, can the demigod truly stay neutral? Without worshippers divine powers wane, the god fears that chaos might arise if the balance is tipped.

Comment: Seems like this is a question dependent upon precisely how they respond to plot events, and how the gods choose to respond to to their responses and so on. If you want them to be spared they will be, if you don't want them to be spared they won't be.

Answer (score 1):

## They would need to actually stay neutral.

Look at politics in our world. Several nations manage to stay neutral, maintaining enough of an army to deter invasion while avoiding being entangled in the politics of the great powers.

However, they need to avoid acts that would violate neutrality. For example, nations that build nuclear bombs aren't seen as neutral, because they have a weapon that could destroy a lot of people.

The demigods released a god killer. That's basically like a nuclear weapon. That's the opposite of neutrality.

Since they're not neutral and are actively seeking to murder the gods, the gods have no reason to remain neutral and not murder them. It's like, if you invade other countries and conquer them, you can't successfully claim military neutrality.

Answer (score 1):

**Special Exemption**

It does not sound like your titan is neutral. It sounds like he has done the gods a huge favour, by returning their weapon, at great personal expense. The threat of the Divine Elephant was the only thing keeping the Gods from declaring open war against the Titans, and now it is gone.

From the Gods' point of view, there is no need to Divine Judge this rogue Titan, because he has already demonstrated he is on our side. Your rogue Titan has more to fear from his fellow Titans taking revenge for re-igniting the war. His best bet is to seek asylum in Olympus for his own protection.

**If you WANT them to be neutral.**

If you want your Titan and their city to remain neutral, then I suggest the following: The Titans originally claimed to have the Divine Peacock and Elephant. The other two animals were still lost.

The titans were like "We have the Elephant and the Peacock. We would hate to have to use them. Leave our airspace immediately"

The Gods were like "yeah bro, you have the big scary animals? Yeah right, I'll believe it when I see it. Oh would you look at the time." and then promptly left their airspace.

Behind all their blustering the Gods were afraid the claims might be true, and this prevented them declaring war. So there was a long stalemate.

The Titan stealing the Elephant both substantiated the claims and leveled the playing field. Now both sides have a superweapon.

The rogue titan has been doing this sort of thing for millennia. Helping one side and then the other in an attempt to keep the game fair. Their ultimate goal is to prevent all-out war from breaking out.

At this stage the stakes are so high neither side wants a war either. This is an open secret in the same way no real country wants nuclear war. Mutually assured destruction. Still they don't want to admit that to the other side, and want to seem strong and willing to go to war at any moment. So they stand at opposite sides of the border and throw rocks at each other.

It suits both sides that Rogue Titan City is a neutral state. It is a good venue for their Peace Summits every century. They go to a neutral ground and bluster and shake their fists and get invited back next year.

Either side has the power to destroy Rogue Titan City  on a whim. But this would be bad for both sides, since they cannot talk to each other anymore. Then their only way to communicate is to blow up successively larger chunks of each others' countries.